# SAPUI5: Execute Code if Binding has Data

Tags: events, data-binding, odata, sapui5

Element binding snippet

```
var oModel = oView.getModel();
var oPromiseMetadataLoaded = oModel.metadataLoaded();
oPromiseMetadataLoaded.then(function() {
    var sObjectPath = oModel.createKey("Project", {
        ProjectID: sProjectId
    });
    oView.bindElement("/" + sObjectPath);
    // <HERE>
});
```

Now I want to execute a function (marked with '// ' where it should go) which uses data from the bound Object. When the data is not there yet (the model is obviously an `OData` model), I need to attach to the `dataReceived` event, but when when the data is already there, this event won't fire.

What is the most (UI5) idiomatic way to execute code in both cases? Is there a Promise like `oModel.metadataLoaded()`? Do I need to consider something, e.g. to probably not read data from an object previously bound to the view?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can attach to the change-Event?

```
oView.bindElement({
        path: "/" + sObjectPath,
        events : {
            change: this._onBindingChange.bind(this),
            dataRequested: function (oEvent) {
                oView.setBusy(true);
            },
            dataReceived: function (oEvent) {
                oView.setBusy(false);
            }
        }
});

_onBindingChange : function (oEvent) {
    if (this.getView().getBindingContext()) {
        //HERE
    }
    else { //Invalid Binding Context };
}
```